# APDE Help: Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers: Lesson 7 Question 3

Tags: partial-differential-equations

can someone help by checking my working and perhaps explain where i'm going wrong?

> solve the following problem with insulated boundaries
>   $$\text{PDE: }~u_t=u_{xx}$$
>   $$ \text{BCs: }~u_x(0,1) = 0~\&~ u_x(1,t)=0$$
>   $$ \text{IC: }~u(x,0)=x$$

we start with solving the PDE by substituting
$$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$
into the above
this gives
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n e^{(-n\pi)^2t}\cos{n\pi x}$$
where $$A_n = 2 \int_{0}^{1} x\cos{n\pi x}$$

then i make $$A_n = 2* \left[ \frac{x\sin{n \pi x}}{n \pi}|_{0}^{1} - \frac{\cos{n \pi x}}{n^2 \pi^2} |_{0}^{1}\right] = -\frac{\cos{n \pi} - 1}{n^2 \pi^2} = \frac{1-(-1)^{n}}{n^2 \pi^2}$$
which alternates between 0 and 2 so letting $n = 2k+1$
$$A_k = \frac{4}{(2k+1)^2 \pi^2}$$
substituting back in and changing the index gives
$$u(x,t) = A_0 + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{4}{(2k+1)^2 \pi^2} e^{(-(2k+1)\pi)^2t}\cos{(2k+1)\pi x}$$
$$u(x,t) = \frac{4}{\pi^2} + \frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{e^{-((2k+1)\pi)^2t}}{(2k+1)^2}\cos{(2k+1)\pi x} $$

which is different from their solution of

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{4}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}e^{-(n\pi)^2t} \cos{n\pi x}$$

any ideas where i went wrong? cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're missing the constant eigen-function, so the full solution is

$$ u(x,t) = A_0 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\cos(n\pi x) $$

The constant is given by

$$ A_0 = \frac{\int_0^1 x\ dx}{\int_0^1 1^2 dx} = \frac12 $$

For the remaining coefficients

$$ A_n = \frac{\int_0^1 x \cos(n\pi x)\ dx}{\int_0^1 \cos^2(n\pi x)\ dx} = 2\int_0^1x\cos(n\pi x)\ dx $$

You made a small sign error at this point. Integration by parts gives

\begin{align} A_n &= \frac{2x\sin(n\pi x)}{n\pi}\Bigg|_0^1 - \int_0^1 \frac{2\sin(n\pi x)}{n\pi}\ dx \\
&= \frac{2\cos(n\pi x)}{n^2\pi^2}\Bigg|_0^1 \\
&= \frac{2}{n^2\pi^2}(\cos(n\pi)-1) \\
&= \frac{2}{n^2\pi^2}((-1)^n-1)
\end{align}

which equals $0$ when $n$ is even and $-\frac{4}{n^2\pi^2}$ when $n$ is odd, so the final solution is

$$ u(x,t) = \frac12 - \sum_{n=2k+1,k=0}^\infty\frac{4}{n^2\pi^2} e^{-n^2\pi^2t}\cos(n\pi x) $$

The answer key probably forgot to say that $n$ needs to be odd.

Comment: hmmm, looks like a couple of silly mistakes on my behalf. thank you!
for the constant eiganfunction, (which im guessing i know as the steady state solution)
your answer makes it look like its the integral of the IC's over the integral of the length squared. am i right in assuming that? or is it more along the lines of the interpolation between two constants undefined by the question (but must be there given the flux is zero at the boundary conditions)?

Comment: Nothing to do with that. The constant function is just part of the eigenfunction set, i.e. solving $X′′+λ2X=0$ when $λ=0$. For convenience, we set the constant equal to $1$. The same steps are taken as the other $A_n$, except with $n$ set to $0$, which results in a different integral and a different normalization. We need this constant function to complete the function space for the initial condition.

Comment: my keyboard has taken this opportunity to break so my apologies
so we solve $$X''+2 \lambda X =0$$
solving and setting $\lambda = 0$ gives $X=A$ where A is a constant.
then from before we have 
$$ A_0 = \frac{\int_0^1 x\ dx}{\int_0^1 cos(0) dx} = \frac12 $$

am i on the right track ??

Comment: The initial function is given by $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_nX_n(x)$, where $$ A_n = \frac{\int_0^1 g(x)X_n(x)\ dx}{\int_0^1 (X_n(x))^2 dx} $$, where $X_0 = 1$ and $X_{n>0} = \cos(n\pi x)$.